# Algorithm of extract eigenvalue and eigenvector from matrix using lower triangular matrix

Tags: algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to compute the eigenvalue of a matrix with this transform:
$$\text{BaseMatrix}\rightarrow \text{LowerTrangularMatrix}$$

and my algorithm of this transform is this:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
    {
        int First=Mat[i][i],Second=Mat[j][i];
        MUL*=First*Second;
        for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
            Mat[i][k]*=Second;
            Mat[j][k]*=First;
        }

        for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
            Mat[j][k]-=Mat[i][k];
    }
```

and then, $Determinant = \text{(multiple of element in Main Diagonal of this matrix)} / MUL$ But where is my eigenvalue?

in other question: can I calculate eigenvector with this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your algorithm (although it seems to be Gaussian eliminations without row swaps), but I'm quite sure it's not correctly implemented. Here is how I tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int MUL = 1, Mat[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{0,4,5},{0,0,6}}, N = 3;

void printData() {
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
      printf("%5d ", Mat[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("MUL = %d\n\n", MUL);
}

int main() {
  int i, j, k;
  printf("The original:\n"); printData();
  for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
    {
        int First=Mat[i][i],Second=Mat[j][i];
        MUL*=First*Second;
        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
        {
            Mat[i][k]*=Second;
            Mat[j][k]*=First;
        }

        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
            Mat[j][k]-=Mat[i][k];
    }
    printf("After i=%d:\n", i); printData();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

```
The original:
    1     2     3
    0     4     5
    0     0     6
MUL = 1

After i=0:
    0     0     0
    0     4     5
    0     0     0
MUL = 0

After i=1:
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
MUL = 0

After i=2:
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
MUL = 0
```

The original matrix has the eigenvalues 1,4,6; the resulting obviously has only zeros and the obtained determinant is undefined ($0/0$).

I've also tried some random non-triangular matrices, but this also tends to gave wrong results. Here is one:

```
The original:
   10    15     9
    0    15     3
    3    14    11
MUL = 1

After i=0:
    0     0     0
    0   150    30
    0     0     0
MUL = 0

After i=1:
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
MUL = 0

After i=2:
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
    0     0     0
MUL = 0
```

The correct eigenvalues are $13 \pm \sqrt{73}$, $10$. This matrix was generated by

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    Mat[i][j] = rand() % 17;
```

If the matrix has no zero elements, the results seem O.K.

However, the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal elements and, for this to be useful, your triangular matrix must be similar to the matrix you started with. Your relations are not similarities and your original matrix gets destroyed in order to compute the determinant, so I don't think you can use this algorithm to obtain either the eigenvalues or the eigenvectors of your matrix.

I have one more remark: your `MUL` grows very quickly. For my test matrices, with elements between $0$ and $16$, it was usually around 11-12 million. This will give you overflow for a fairly small matrices. For example, this one fails:

```
Mat[5][5] = {{2, 4, 5, 3, 7}, {3, 9, 4, 16, 14}, {4, 16, 11, 4, 15}, {15, 13, 16, 7, 12}, {1, 3, 11, 9, 15}};
```

The correct determinant is $23544$, but you get `MUL = 0` and the transformed matrix

```
  360   720   900   540  1260
    0 -42301440 49351680 -162155520 -49351680
    0     0 -713031680 452984832 159383552
    0     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     0     0
```

This could probably get fixed by dividing the $i$-th row with `MUL` after the each pass through the outside loop (also resetting `MUL` back to $1$). For this, you'll need the real arithmetic. Alternatively, you could - in each step - divide rows of your matrix by $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $MUL = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$. Such $x_k$ should be easy to find and the whole thing should be doable in the integer arithmetic.

There is one more reason you cannot easily change this to compute the eigenvalues: they can be non-real. For example, the previous ($5 \times 5$) matrix has the eigenvalues $45.3112$, $-3.37164 + 8.44951 i$, $-3.37164 - 8.44951 i$, $3.76423$, $1.66789$.